# What does this linking error mean?

Tags: linker, ld, shared-libraries

When I was compiling a new software, I encountered a bunch of errors emitted by `ld`.

```
/usr/lib/libstreamanalyzer.so.0: undefined reference to `xmlSAXUserParseMemory@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libstreamanalyzer.so.0: undefined reference to `xmlCtxtResetPush@LIBXML2_2.6.1'
/usr/lib/libstreamanalyzer.so.0: undefined reference to `xmlCreatePushParserCtxt@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
```

This seems to be confusing. Linker is supposed to be looking for symbols in objects, not library names, but it seems in this case those before the *@* is the function name/symbol, and `LIBXML2_2.6.1` is a library name. And for dynamic library, the *soname* x.y.z version should only matter in dynamic linking stage, that is when the executable actually runs.

So what does this error really means, and what part of the above assumptions are wrong?

Edit:

The problem appears after installing libxml2 2.7.8. It is gone after libxml2 is upgraded to 2.9.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I was compiling a new software, I encountered a bunch of errors

No, you didn't. You encountered errors when *linking*, which is different from *compiling*.

> Linker is supposed to be looking for symbols in objects

UNIX linkers also look for symbols in libraries (both archive and shared).

> LIBXML2_2.6.1 is a library name

No, it's not. It's a symbol *version*, which happens to reflect the library in which that symbol was defined.

> So what does this error really means

This error means: when `libstreamanalyzer.so.0` was linked, it was linked against a library (most likely `libxml2.so`) that provided versioned symbols `xmlSAXUserParseMemory@LIBXML2_2.4.30`, etc.

You are now linking your binary against some other version of `libxml2`, one which does *not* provide these symbols, and your binary will not work.

Comment: OK. So this is a GNU "feature", and is not part of standard *C* or *C++*.

Comment: The standard `C` or `C++` has no concept of source file, object file, or a library. But yes: versioned symbols are a GNU extension to POSIX.

Comment: Both C and C++ standard has something called *Standard Library* afaik.